# Use a keystore with Talend Administration Center

Tags: ssl, keystore, talend

I have a job in which i need to use a keystore. In JVM params i have : -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="/appli/TalendTools-5.6.1/myfile.com.ks"

It perfectly works on my desktop when i launch my job with the studio, but when i try to launch it with the TAC (remote server) i get a message :

```
...
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
"/appli/TalendTools-5.6.1/myfile.com.ks" 
(No such file or directory)
```

Obviously my file is really there and folders and file have 777 rights
Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that the key file exists in that location on the relevant job execution server? The error seems to imply otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and i found the cause:

you set the variable like this: `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="/appli/TalendTools-5.6.1/myfile.com.ks"`, the wrong bit is the `"` character that is considered as part of the path.

the FileNotFoundException does not add any additional decoration to the path and correctly says cannot find the path `"/appli/TalendTools-5.6.1/myfile.com.ks"`

so the solution is set the variable as:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/appli/TalendTools-5.6.1/myfile.com.ks`

and in case of spaces in the path use exec to ran java in this way:

`exec java "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/appli/TalendTools-5.6.1/myfile with space.com.ks" Main.class`